# document.getElementbyId in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, image, document, getelementbyid

I have a div that I want to put one image inside, how could I do something like that:

Javascript:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML + "<img src='farmer.gif'>";
</script>
```

Html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id = "people"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

in PHP? Im so fustrated I can do it in JS but I need to do it in PHP but I don't know how...

Hope you can help me! :D

Comment: I'm almost certain of putting a div inside an image will result in invalid html.

Comment: @MarkRijsmus OP wants to put an `img` inside of a `div`, it's just worded badly

Comment: JS is client side, meaning it can detect things after being made. PHP is server side and usually done before HTML is generated so at that point, no ID's exist yet.

Comment: @dwhite.me — Usually, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast VERY DIRTY WAY:
do `ob_start();`  at the first line of the script

do `echo  "<div>%imag1flag%</div>";`

do `$content = ob_get_clean();`  at the end of the script

change contnet with `$content = str_replace('%imag1flag%','<img ...>',$content);`

But wonder why you didnt paste the image in the first place eg:

`echo "<div><img ...></div>";`

Keep in Mind  Javascript is `Statefull` PHP is `NOT Statefull`.

When u got that, maybe you will laugth about your Question ;)

Bye!